# Migrating from JCA to OSGI Is it a good idea?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, osgi, jboss7.x, jca

I have a JCA adapter for connecting to EIS. 
Is it a good idea to replace the adapter with an OSGI module?

The features I need are

1. Access the OSGI module from ejb3
2. Access the OSGI module from CDI beans
3. Access the OSGI module from a servlet
4. Support declarative transaction mangement
5. Propogate security context from ejb to osgi module

   - I dont use conection pooling.
   - I dont use Common Client interface

What are the cons of moving from JCA to OSGI module ?

Answer (score 1):

The cons of moving are:

- JCA is a Java EE standard - you can use a properly written connector in any Java EE container. Osgi is also a standard but not (yet) for Enterprise Applications and their frameworks.
- All your listed "features" (I would call them "requirements") are tightly coupled to Java EE: EJB3, CDI, Servlet, TXN management and security are all done or provided by the various Java EE subsystems. You will have to dive *deeply* into the Java EE specs to provide the appropriate glue code.

This boils down to: A lot of error-prone work for no good reason. So my question would be: What are the *pros* for moving (in your case of course)?

Comment: JEE has very good support to RDBMS based data stores.Integrating no-sql or an object database is an involved process. ie, write a JCA adapter, add an ra.xml , configure a datasource. With OSGI i expect the integration process will be lot simpler. Just drop the osgi bundle in the class path and start using the tx-mgt, declarative security and other nice features of JEE. API could be as simple as @inject NOSQLPersistanceManager

Comment: The hard part - writing the JCA code is comparable to OSGI when you need the advanced JCA contracts like XA-transactions. The ra.xml does not matter in terms of effort. And the _configuration_ of the DS will be required for OSGI also - or would you hardcode the connection parameters into you OSGI-Bundle? Con for OSGI: With JEE/JCA you get a lot of infrastructure for free - with OSGI you will have to reinvent some wheels only to get on par with that - especially in your case because you want still to have access to EJB3,...